# Fired from 4-month job in which I gained experience and skills working as a cashier and in food service

Tags: termination

In 2017, I worked at an amusement park for about 4 months and got experience working as a cashier and at multiple different restaurants and other food/drink service locations in the park such as Tim Hortons, an ice cream truck, pizza pizza, drink stations, etc.

But then, so unfortunately, one day, close to the end of my term working at the amusement park for the summer, when I was working at a drink station, a customer gave me $5 and because my cash register was already closed, I thought it was a tip and pocketed it. You don't have to believe this story, but honestly it's what I thought and it was a mistake that could happen to me after doing over 200 transactions in one day and being someone with ADHD. A surveillance worker witnessed this, and long story short I got fired.

Is it possible for me to use this somehow on my resume to prove that I have experience working as a cashier and at tim hortons and pizza to get such jobs? Or should I keep it off my resume forever?

Comment: If you do put them down as previous work experience, and they call the manager to verify it, what would the manager say?

Comment: Since this isn't a new problem, and you were fired back in 2017, have you kept it off your resume.  Understanding what you have been doing, for the last 18 months, might help the community formulate a better answer.

Comment: The customer gave you $5? For what? Did the customer think it was a tip? The lack of detail makes me suspect that while you misjudged the situation, the customer and the surveillance did not. If you think the skills you learned are valuable going forward it might be worth listing, but I wouldn't give them as a reference.

Comment: When I worked at the amusement park, I got transferred around a lot. This may have been a dumb thing to do, but after I got fired, I told one of my managers the story to ask if I could use her as a reference despite being fired. She said yes, and that she asked the other manager of my normal restaurant and he also said I could use him as a reference. So I guess if they called the manager, they may say that I got fired if they still remember, and if they called the amusement park, the park should have a record that I was fired.

Comment: I have mostly kept it off my resume, except for when I was applying for jobs shortly after I got fired. Since then, I have worked at Canadian Tire for 5 months and volunteered at a law firm for 4 months. But as you can see, I don't have much work experience.

Comment: So SiXandSeven8ths, you mean I can use the company as work experience but I shouldn't use anyone from the company as a reference? That would be fine for me, since I don't use anyone from there as a reference, even though as I previously commented, my actual managers said that I could use them as a reference. My worry is more with having work experience on my resume.

Comment: Oh and SiXandSeven8ths, the thing is by this point I'm sure the customer knew it was the payment, but it was my mistake to think they already payed since my cash register was closed. I think the customer and the surveillance did not misjudge the situation and it was my mistake. So it would be seen as I stole the property of the amusement park, but really it was a mistake and it was just $5, when in that day I made over $2000 or even $3000 for the amusement park.

Comment: You admit it was your fault but I'm curious:the customer paid for whatever they bought and because your register was closed you put it in your pocket. Did you afterwards declare it somewhere or gave it to superiors? If not, you didn't mistake it for a tip but clearly stole it and I share the parks reason for firing you. You should have either re-opened your register, decline business to the customer or immediately update your books with the additional 5$ for items sold.

Answer (score 6):

If you know anyone who can do a verification of employment call, have them call the park and do that to see what they say.

If you get a good response, add them, if not or if you cannot get someone to do a test verification, leave them off.  A summer job isn't going to make or break your resume.

***EXCEPTION***

If you are required to fill out an application that says  **LIST ALL EMPLOYMENT** you have to list them.

Should the issue ever arise, address it as directly and honestly as you can.

> Yeah, I ended up getting fired because I confused a payment for a tip.  I've learned to be much more careful since then, and whenever there is any question, I always get verification from the customer and management

See what I did there?  You say a blurb about what happened, but then go right into what you've done since then to make sure it never happens again.  That way **YOU** answer the question before they can ask it.

Good luck.

Comment: I could possibly ask the placement advisor at my college to do the test verification call. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: That is interesting though how you say I would have to list it if in an application asked LIST ALL EMPLOYMENT. They can really find out everywhere you've worked if you exclude the company from where you were fired?

Comment: @JohnMifed Yes, they can.  NEVER lie on an application.  Now, this will eventually age out and the application will say "List all jobs in the past "X" years.  So, don't worry about it too much, it won't haunt you forever.

Comment: Very nicely put, @RichardU .   Life is **all about word combinations**.